# Vaadin databinding between ListSelect and java.util.List<String>

Tags: data-binding, collections, vaadin

I am new to vaadin and have a databinding problem. I have posted allready in the vaadin forum, but no answer up to now.
if you answer here, I will of course reward it anyway.

https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1057226

thanks in advance.
greets,
Andreas

Additional information: I tried allready to iterate over the items in the container, after pressing a save button. After deleting all original elements in the model collection, and adding copies from the container, the GUI breaks. Some other GUI elements do not respond anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have personally never used ListSelect, but I found this from the [API docs](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html):

> This is a simple list select without, for instance, support for new items, lazyloading, and other advanced features.

I'd recommend `BeanItemContainer`. You can use it like this:

```
// Create a list of Strings
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("Hello");

// Create a BeanItemContainer and include strings list
final BeanItemContainer<String> container = new BeanItemContainer<String>(strings);
container.addBean("World");

// Create a ListSelect and make BeanItemContainer its data container
ListSelect select = new ListSelect("", container);

// Create a button that adds "!" to the list
Button button = new Button("Add to list", new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        container.addBean("!");
    }
}

// Add the components to a layout
myLayout.addComponent(button);
myLayout.addComponent(select);
```

The downside (or benefit, it depends :) of this is that you can't add duplicate entries to a BeanItemContainer. In the example above the exclamation mark gets only added once.

You can get a Collection of Strings by calling:

```
Collection<String> strings = container.getItemIds();
```

If you need to support duplicate entries, take a look at [IndexedContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html). With IndexedContainer you can add a String property by calling `myIndexedContainer.addContainerProperty("caption", String.class, "");` and give each Item a unique itemId (or let the container generate the id's automatically).

Comment: This add's the new lines to the ListSelect, but not to the strings ArrayList, which is the data model, I need to use later. Is it possible, they create a databinding, which works only in one direction out of the box?

Comment: Updated my answer. I wouldn't use an ArrayList as a data model. You can use the BeanItemContainer as the data model. Or does it specifically have to be ArrayList?

Comment: the reason for this is, I have an Repository Component I have to use, which deliveres a ArrayList (or if needed an other collection). But this brings me to a possible solution. If this Repository deliveres a Container, with items and properties, then it would be all fine.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I understand your problem but I belive that it might be that you haven't told the controller to repaint. You do this be setting the datasource like this after the save event has occured.

```
listSelect.setContainerDataSource(listSelect.getContainerDataSource());
```

Comment: This did not solve the problems, but it is good to know, how to trigger a repaint